# Preventing linebreaks between firstname and surname in a sequence of authors

Tags: expl3

I've got a list of authors given in a `expl3`-sequence and want to apply a function on each item of the sequence and return it as a list. Starting with `expl3` I cannot figure out how to do that and I'm getting unexpected results:

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_author_seq

\NewDocumentCommand \authors { m }
{ \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq  {~and~} { #1 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\par}\par\bigskip

  While~this~worked~as~expected,~the~following~didn't:\par
  \seq_set_map:NNn   \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq {\fbox{#1}}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {\par}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}\sffamily

\authors{Susan Ferrari and Zoe Schmid and Akari Demirci}

\bigskip

And I expected an output like

\fbox{Susan Ferrari}\par
\fbox{Zoe Schmid}\par
\fbox{Akari Demirci}
\end{document}
```

Hoping that I will understand the `interface3`-documentation at some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument of `\seq_set_map:NNn` is an `<inline function>` in which `#1` is each item in the sequence being mapped.  However you are using `\seq_set_map:NNn` *inside* the definition of `\authors` so you have to use `##1` instead of `#1` there.

Inside the definition of `\authors`, `#1` is the string `Susan Ferrari and Zoe Schmid and Akari Demirci`, which means that your code did roughly:

```latex
\seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \fbox{Susan Ferrari and Zoe Schmid and Akari Demirci} }
```

so you can see why the output you got.

Also, `\seq_set_map:NNn` does an `x`-expansion of its third argument, so you have to prefix `\fbox` with `\exp_not:N`, just to be safe.

> [image]

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_author_seq

\NewDocumentCommand \authors { m }
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq  {~and~} { #1 }
    \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\par}  \par\bigskip
  
    While~this~worked~as~expected,~the~following~didn't:\par
    \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \exp_not:N \fbox{##1} }
    \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {\par}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}\sffamily

\authors{Susan Ferrari and Zoe Schmid and Akari Demirci}

\bigskip

And I expected an output like

\fbox{Susan Ferrari}\par
\fbox{Zoe Schmid}\par
\fbox{Akari Demirci}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! One `#` :) And thanks for the explanation regarding the expansion. I still have troubles wrapping my brain around expansion-issues.

Comment: @ChristianAndersen You're welcome!  In the specific case of `\fbox`, it seems to work fine without `\exp_not:N`, but if you do `\seq_show:N \l_tmpb_seq` after the `\seq_set_map:NNn` line, you'll see why it needs `\exp_not:N`.  Also it looks to me that `\seq_set_map:NNn` should be called `\seq_set_map:NNx` instead...

Comment: So I tried `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_map:NNn { NNx }` and replacing `\seq_set_map:NNn` with NNx (`\seq_set_map:NNx   \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq {\exp_not:N \fbox{#1}}`). But `\seq_show:N`-output now looks awful again. Could you explain me, why NNx should be better?

Comment: @ChristianAndersen Because then `\seq_set_map:NNx` will `x`-expand the argument twice, but `\exp_not:N` only protects against _one_ expansion.  What I meant is that I think the name of `\seq_set_map:NNn` is wrong in the kernel and should probably be fixed (I opened an issue here: https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/766).  Your code seems fine as it is.

Comment: @ChristianAndersen I changed `\seq_set_map:NNn` so that it no longer expands the `<inline function>`, so the `\exp_not:N` should be removed in your case, and I also renamed the old `x`-expanding version to `\seq_set_map_x:NNn` (see this PR: https://github.com/latex3/latex3/pull/772).  If you have TeXLive 2020 or MiKTeX, then the update should be available in about two or three days.